# How can reduce improve my ANN accuracy and reduce overfitting?

Tags: neural-networks, python, keras, pandas

My ANN model produces classic overfitting characteristics, producing high R2 values (90-99%) but low accuracy scores (10-40%). I'm currently inputting 28655 data entries, using 8 input features to predict solar radiation.

My model is as follows:

```
df = pd.read_csv (r'D:\ABC Masters Diss\Penarth 1 year.csv')
print (df)
df[:5]

df.info()

#Features
X = df[["Cloud Coverage", "Probability of Precipitation", "Dry Bulb Temp", "Dew Point Temp", "Relative Humidity", "Apparent Temp", "Time of Day", "Month"]]

#Target
Y = df["Solar Radiation"]

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, 
                                                    Y, 
                                                    test_size = 0.2)

scaler = StandardScaler()

X_train_std = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test_std = scaler.transform(X_test)

#Initialise the ANN
model = Sequential()

#Input layer and hidden layer
model.add(Dense(50, activation= 'relu', input_dim = 8))

#second layer
model.add(Dense(units = 50, activation = 'relu'))

#output layer
model.add(Dense(units = 1))

model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mean_squared_error', metrics = ['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train_std, Y_train, batch_size = 10, epochs = 10)

pred_a1 = model.predict(X_test_std)
pd.DataFrame({"Actual": Y_test, "Predicted": pred_a1.flatten()})[:5]
```

I've tried altering the architecture, no. of layers & neurons etc. I've also tried changing the activation, adding drop out and kernel constraints and altering the learning rate(see below). Any ideas on how to improve this?

```
#Input layer and hidden layer
model.add(Dense(50, activation= 'relu', input_dim = 8, kernel_constraint=MaxNorm(3)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
#second layer
model.add(Dense(units = 50, activation = 'relu', kernel_constraint=MaxNorm(3)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
#output layer
model.add(Dense(units = 1, activation = 'relu'))

sgd = SGD(learning_rate=0.01, momentum=0.9)
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mean_squared_error', metrics = ['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train_std, Y_train, batch_size = 10, epochs = 100)
```

Comment: Make sure your test data is ok. are you sure that rows in your dataset are independent? Using `train_test_split` assumes they are, but your data doesn't look so... if there is temporary correlation between rows, then train_test_split can't be used. That said, try a simpler model. Reduce the number of neurons and layers. Drop out may also help. Also include the loss function wile training for both, train and validation to see how it evolves.

Comment: Also I didn't get why are you evaluating both, accuracy and R2... The first is used for classification problems and the second for regression. How are you computing them?

Comment: [What should I do when my neural network doesn't learn?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/352036/what-should-i-do-when-my-neural-network-doesnt-learn/352037#352037)

Comment: How is high $R^2$ and low accuracy an indication of overfitting? // @RodrigoLaguna $R^2$ is a totally legitimate way to evaluate the probability outputs and is equivalent to using the Brier score.